# how to set values dynamically to javascript var

Tags: javascript

i've a requirement to set the values dynamically into js var, which i will use it to set to sapui5 model .

but i'm unable to do that. 
http://jsbin.com/fubobuvoqi/1/edit?html,console
here, i'm unable to set next value into the array:

```
data.a.b.c[1].c1 = "234";
console.log(data.a.b.c[1].c1);
```

is it possible do that way, or its completely wrong way of doing it.. what is best way of doing this?

i want to grow my c array dynamically.

Comment: Simple that is because you don't have `c[1]`, that is undefined, so it's giving error.

Comment: ya, how can i grow my array? i want to set values and grow array

Comment: can it be like, initially i will just have the structure and then i can grow depending on the requirement?

Comment: arrays has a method called as `push` which will add the given element as the last element.

Comment: [edited bin](http://jsbin.com/dumumurepo/2/edit)

Comment: I hope you got an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assing it, cause it's really doesn't exist yet (undefined), but you can create it using [push()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
try to change

```
data.a.b.c[1].c1 = "234";
```

to

```
data.a.b.c.push({c1: "234"});
```

this will add one more element to array and make you var look like

```
  c : [
    {
      c1 : "987",
      c2 : 987,
      c3 : "987.00"
    },
    {
      c1 : "234"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: thanks vladkras. both of u've answered my question. and I could only make ur post as answer. and i cant vote up (<15 votes). tnx to both again.

Comment: you are welcome! stay with us on SO and everything will be possible for you